# phpMyAdmin is not working in ubuntu 20.04 with php7.4 there is blank screen

Tags: phpmyadmin

I updated ubuntu to the version 20.04 and before the update PHPmyadmin was working fine, there is blank screen and internal error 500. I have reinstalled and followed the instructions to install phpmyadmin on ubuntu 20.04, but it is not working, have some one same error? is there any solution? is there mandatory to have ssh installed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, it is due because at some point during the update I have updated php and there were running both versions, so I had to disable 7.0 from apache and enable the new 7.4, and it has worked, I realized that some other programs that I have with PHP were not working either, but part of them were running fine. Once I applied the change it worked fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After the update of ubuntu 20.04 I noticed that the version of php has become 8.0 which poses the malfunction of phpmyadmin

---

1 Try to check your php version

```
php -v
```

if you get this

> PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2021 08:22:35) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.0.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

2 .try to  remove php 8 by using this command

```
sudo apt-get remove purge php8.*
```

3. then

   sudo apt install phpmyadmin

Comment: Do you confirm that php8.0 still causes this issue with phpmyadmin? I use php8.0 and when I try to access phpmyadmin I only receive a blank page.
Is this issue reported somewhere? I'm looking for opened threads with Google but I found only this one.